# JSlider Problems

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a program that uses scroll bars to select the foreground color for a label, three horizontal scroll bars are used for selecting the red green and blue components of the color. I need a title border on the panel that holds the scroll bars. I have only started it. I am having problems with this messagePanel.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MessagePanel extends JPanel
{
    //The message to be displayed
    private String message;
    //The x-Coordinate
    private int xCoordinate;
    //The y-Coordinate
    private int yCoordinate;
    //Centered
    private boolean centered;
    //Interval length for moving message horizontally and vertically
    private int interval = 10;

    public MessagePanel()
    {
    }

    //Construct message panel with a specific message
    public MessagePanel(String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    //Return that specific message
    public String getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }

    //Set a new message
    public void setMessage(String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
        repaint();
    }

    //Return xCoordinate
    public int getXCoordinate()
    {
        return xCoordinate;
    }

    //Set a new xCoordinate
    public void setXCoordinate(int x)
    {
        this.xCoordinate = x;
        repaint();
    }

    //Return yCoordinate
    public int getYCoordinate()
    {
        return yCoordinate;
    }

    //Set a new yCoordinate
    public void setYCoordinate(int y)
    {
        this.yCoordinate = y;
        repaint();
    }

    //Return Centered
    public boolean isCentered()
    {
        return centered;
    }

    //Set a new Centered
    public void setCenetered(boolean centered)
    {
        this.centered = centered;
    }

    //Return interval
    public int getInterval()
    {
        return interval;
    }

    //Set a new interval
    public void setInterval(int interval)
    {
        this.interval = interval;
        repaint();
    }

    //Paint the Message
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (centered)
        {
            //Current metrics for current font
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();

            //Find the center location to display                                               
            int stringWidth = fm.stringWidth(message);
            int stringAscent = fm.getAscent();

            //Get the position of the leftmost char in the baseline
            int xCoordinate = getWidth() / 2 - stringWidth / 2;
            int yCoordinate = getHeight() / 2 + stringAscent / 2;
        }

        //Draw String   
        g.drawString(message, xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
    }

    //Move the message to the left
    public void moveLeft()
    {
        xCoordinate -= interval;
        repaint();
    }

    //Move the message to the right
    public void moveRight()
    {
        xCoordinate += interval;
        repaint();
    }

    //Move the message up
    public void moveUp()
    {
        yCoordinate -= interval;
        repaint();
    }

    //Move the message down
    public void moveDown()
    {
        yCoordinate += interval;
        repaint();
    }

    //Override get method for preferredSize
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(200, 30);
    }
}
```

This is may ScrollBar class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class ScrollBar extends JFrame
{
    //Creating scroll bars
    private JSlider jslHorz1 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL);
    private JSlider jslHorz2 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL);
    private JSlider jslHorz3 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL);

    //Creating the message panel
    private MessagePanel messagePanel = new MessagePanel("Show Color");

    //Adding scroll bars and message panel
    public ScrollBar(){
        //Creating UI
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(3, 3));

        //Adding messagePanel
        add(messagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Adding the scroll bars
        JPanel three = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
        three.add(new JLabel("Red"));
        three.add(jslHorz1);
        three.add(new JLabel("Green"));
        three.add(jslHorz2);
        three.add(new JLabel("Blue"));
        three.add(jslHorz3);
        add(three, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        three.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Choose Color"));



    }

    //Main method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ScrollBar frame = new ScrollBar();
        frame.setTitle("Exercise 17_15");
        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //  frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"...  I am having problems with this messagePanel."` -- you will want to tell us exactly what these problems are, else we will have a hard time trying to help you. Please also tell us exactly what these classes are trying to do. Give us any information that can help us to better understand your code and your problem, as anything that speeds up our understanding of all this, speeds our ability to help.

Comment: Can't you use a JSlider or JSpinner to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you a basic idea of what I would do **quick and dirty** (from your description, your code seems to strange for me).

1. Set up a container (JFrame, JPanel, ...) holding the JLabel (you said "label" and used JPanel) and three controls for RGB. Free choice here - just make sure they give you valid values somehow.
2. Set the controls to values from 0 to 255 (which should be the range for each color)
3. Bind a value-based Listener to the three RGB controls of your choice (this may differ depending on your choise of control).
4. Make the Listener change to JLabel's color when you change one the their values by reading every controls value.

You can use the JLabel's methods to set each of it's colors.